# dropdown attribute with city instead country

Tags: attributes

is possibile to duplicate country_of_manufactor changing the source data and show region (or city) instead country?
I try to find a solution but nothing

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are looking for is a way to change the Countries? Into region?

I believe this has already been answered.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195216/how-to-add-new-state-province-and-city-dropdown-in-magento-1-6-2

Good Luck!

Comment: and for add the dropdown into backend?